# How to Convert days of week into numbers for correlation calculation using R

Tags: r, string, numeric, correlation

Is there an accepted way to handle **converting the days of the week from text to numeric values for calculating the correlation coefficient in R** ?

Should I use dummyVars maybe using the caret package in R and treat them as categorical or is there a better way to avoid any possible dummy variable trap or data loss?

Maybe the following sample table will help the discussion (*just show the code snippet and run to see a very basic table)*

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>PurchaseDay</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>ReturnDay</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Tractor</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Tues</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Bus</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>Tractor</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Tues</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it important that Mon and Monday get the same numeric coding even though they are in different columns? 
What is the standard way of representing days of the week as numbers in R so I can create a numeric representation of the data and pass it to the corr()

Comment: At least to me it's unclear what exactly you want to achieve. If you're looking for an analysis of the number of sales on each day of the week, you could just do a plain sum / mean, and then a histogram of the days at which products were returned. What information are you looking for? Essentially you're dealing with a categorical vs. continuous variable problem, so maybe [this answer on Stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112674) helps? In addition, since you're asking for an R solution, please provide copyable R example code.

Comment: @jhin I'm afraid my R skills aren't up to sharing example code at the moment. Its more of where do I start and what R libraries or functions can help me type of question. I apologise if I wasn't clear given a dataset containing dates and categorical columns how do I calculate correlation to see the relationship (if any) between values. And Given corr() requires numeric data how do I handle the date values as I assumed it was useful to reduce them to DayOfWeek Values instead of full date-time values to begin with (outside R) I plan to read the data from a database and then use R

Comment: My first thought is to use the caret package and create dummy vars for the non numeric columns but is that the best way to pre-process DaysOfWeek?

Comment: What I am questioning in the first place is whether you really want to calculate the coefficient of correlation. What is the kind of result that you are hoping for? The correlation is really only defined for continuous variables, and that is where it makes sense. You're dealing with 2 categorical variables, however. The calculated coefficient of correlation will strongly depend on the way you convert your days to numbers, e.g. to which day you assign the smallest number, etc... I am by no means a statistics expert, but this seems a very questionable method to me.

Comment: I'd like to know the relationship between columns, while I'm only talking about 2 columns here the dataset I'm trying to understand contains over 50 columns with only 1 or 2 numeric columns with the rest categorical or DaysOfWeek